# Tomcat runs different application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat8

I am developing a spring boot app with embeded tomcat server. When I start the project from spring and run it, I see the application which I ran on Virtual machine(windows)'s localhost while I should see my application which I am developing. It's strange that I see the application from virtual machine even when VM is shut down. Does it mean the tomcat has stored it in cache? How do I delete that data? I am using mac OS catalina.

Answer (score 0):

Once run the below command in your terminal to kill your localhost then try

```
 kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:8080)
```